# Change $JAVA_HOME in python script

Tags: java, python

I've tried to make a python script to switch between 32bit and 64 bit java but for some reason

```
os.system('export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/path') 
os.system('export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH')
```

does nothing, but manually it works. How can I fix this? (BTW, this is running on a Linux system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `export` line will set an environment variable for the shell in which it's executed and all its sub-shells. But what's happening here is that Python creates a new shell, executes the line to set the environment variable, and then the shell terminates. That means the environment variable is no longer in force. In fact, the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable you set in the first line isn't even in force for the second line when that gets executed, because that's in its own shell that also terminates immediately!

The way round it is to run a whole shell script that sets the environment variable and then launches Java:

```
#!/bin/bash

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/path
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

java ...
```

Comment: Thanks I've got the point . I've added to script line with "run of .jar file and it is working"

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are local to each process. If you want to make a permanent change then you can follow the official java [PATH instructions](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml). They recommend adding the export variable command to your .bashrc file.

In ~/.bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/path
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the commands together - jdk set + script execution like this:

```
setJdk4Gradle = 'export JAVA_HOME=/home/jdkPath && export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
os.system(setJdk4Gradle + ' && executeSomething')
```